# Can not post value from one domain(angular js) to another domain(laravel) using $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.3

I am working with Angular Js and Laravel.In angular js I have used route provider to send request from angular js to laravel.

In angular js I have create route js where I include html template using **$routeProvider**. Here,below is **route.js**

```
var app = angular.module("supportApp",['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '../views/home.html',
            controller: 'AdminController'
        }).         
        when('/masters/countries', {
            templateUrl: '../views/masters/countries.html'
        });
}
]);
```

Now, I have created masters.js where all masters controller are stored in.Here you can see **masters.js**

```
app.controller('CountriesController',function($scope,$http){
    var countries = this;
    $http.get("http://api.local.support.com/masters/countries")
    .then(function mySuccess(responce) {
        countries.countrydata = responce["data"]["data"];
    });

    this.saveAdd = function() {
        console.log(countries.countries);
        $http.post("http://api.local.support.com/masters/countries/store",countries.countries)
        .then(function mySuccess(response) {
             console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```

Here, I have create middleware in laravel to accept request from another domain. **Cors.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])           
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '10000')
             ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }
}
```

My countries.html page is look likes below :

```
<div ng-controller="CountriesController as country">
    <div class="modal fade" id="addNew" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icons-office-52"></i></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add New Country</strong>    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field-1" class="control-label">Country</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="country.countries.name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field-1" class="control-label">Sortname</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alias" ng-model="country.countries.sortname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-embossed" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-embossed" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="country.saveAdd()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, get method in angular js is working perfet. But it gives an error in post method.

**Error :** XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.local.support.com/masters/countries/store. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://local.support.com' is therefore not allowed access.

**Note :** Here I have created two vertual host `http://api.local.support.com` for laravel and `http://local.support.com` for angular js and view file.

So, How can I resolve this Error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: @Slava.K How can I check and  How to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know because I've never got my questions marked as duplicate :D. You probably should have "close" link under your question in UI. If it exists just click it and follow procedure

Comment: @Slava.K I have follow that link but I could not understand what it is because I am in learning stage in both angular and laravel.